# mod_rewrite, .htaccess connecting to mysql database

Tags: mysql, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like mod_rewrite in an .htaccess file to link to a mysql database to provide me with mapping information.

Specifically, I am using a single code base to host multiple sites so..if a user requests an image, for example:
http://www.example.com/images/car.jpg

this is going to hit my server and many other sites will also be hitting that /images folder, so I need Apache to reply with:
/home/example/pubic_html/images/7383/car.jpg

Notice the injection of "7383" which is an example site id for that user.

Basically, I want to map between example.com and 7383 using the mysql database and then get the correct file to the user.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a script as a [rewrite map](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) to get the real path.

Comment: Been there. Done that. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

RewriteMap is the correct Apache functionality to use. Thank you Gumbo.

Somethings to note as I worked through this:

- RewriteMap goes in your Apache config instead of in the .htaccess file
- I wrote a script to build a mapping text file that will perform the mapping that I had above. It basically dumps from the database whatever is necessary -- since mine does not change every minute, I can just run a periodic dump into this text file whenever mapping is added or changed.

Works like a champ. Thanks Apache for this wonderful tool.