# .htaccess from dynamic to static(from id to name from database)

Tags: .htaccess, dynamic, static

I have one problem. How can I change the dynamic address to a static one, like shown below:
from:
 www.something.net/default.asp?lang=en&page=10&id=22
to:
www.something.net/jacket

In my database(MS access) I have a table called Items(colums id and name). At id=22, I have an item named jacket

I want to do this only by re-programing the .htaccess file..Any idea or good example? Read previous posts about it, but didn't quite figure it out yet.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you would need to use a rewrite map - your question is very similar to [mod_rewrite, .htaccess connecting to mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451214/mod-rewrite-htaccess-connecting-to-mysql-database).

You could also have a sheet of formulas, or macro that converts your spreadsheet into a set of rewrite rules, and then paste/save this into a htaccess file.